# Read value from a specific object that is inside another object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that may be something like this:

```
Object {data: Object, status: "OK"}
```

In this case `data` is another object that might look something like:

```
0: Object
1: Object
...
```

Finally inside each individual object in data holds the actual info I am interested in, for example

```
0: Object
  name: "somename"
  fax: "somenum"
```

How can I specifically read the value of `name` from Object 0?

Comment: try `obj.data[0].name` where `obj` is the object variable.

Comment: Why confuse us with such bizzare description of structure? use a common representation: JSON.

Comment: @Amit the OP obviously don't know how to do that.

Comment: @avrahamcool - OP obviously does (`{data: Object, status: "OK"}`)

Comment: @Amit it's obvious he copy/pasted it from somewhere. if he knew what JSON was, he wouldn't need our help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested objects can be referenced by just reference their property name.  So, if you have multiple levels of nested objects like this:

```
var myvar = {
    data: {
        moreData: {
            name: "somename",
            fax: "somenum"
        }
    }
};
```

Then, you can reference the name like this:

```
var name = myvar.data.moreData.name;
```

In Javascript property names used with the dot notation as above must be strings, so if your properties (as shown in your question were `0`), then you'd can use the `["propname"]` syntax like this:

```
var myvar = {
    data: {
        "0": {
            name: "somename",
            fax: "somenum"
        }
    }
};

var name = myvar.data["0"].name;
```

or

```
var name = myvar.data[0].name;
```

because you can't do this:

```
var name = myvar.data.0.name;
```

because the Javascript syntax doesn't allow a dot referenced property name to start with a number.

---

P.S. If your objects are actually arrays, like this:

```
var myvar = {
    data: [{
              name: "somename",
              fax: "somenum"
            },
            {
              name: "someothername",
              fax: "someothernum"
            }
          ]
};
```

Then, you can use syntax like this:

```
var name = myvar.data[0].name;
var name = myvar.data[1].name;
```

Comment: the inner data structure in the question looks more like an array.

Comment: @avrahamcool - the OP refers to it as an object with numeric-like property names so that's how I phrased the answer.  I've shown how to deal with those types of properties in the answer now too.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Does this not attempt to teach the user how to access nested objects which is what they are asking to do?  What do you think this answer is missing?

Comment: For some reason these guys woke up on the wrong side of the bed today and are downvoting everything en masse. Yes they are actually objects, that's how I get the data, cant do anything about it for now. You suggestion works but I dont think you need to enclose the 0 with double quotes. I also apologize if the way I phrased the question was confusing, I thought it would be better to describe it with words rather than copy pasting some JSON string.

Comment: @dearn44 - Yes, Javascript will allow `[0]` to work (it will auto-convert to a string), but if it's not an array and since the property name is actually a string, I prefer to use a string when accessing it and not rely on auto-convert.

Comment: you don't need to 'enclose the 0 with double quotes' because your data structure is an array and not an object so the access is via indexer and not property name (and that is the reason of the downvote) and NOT because JS will convert it to a string..

Comment: @avrahamcool - My data structure in my answer is NOT an array.  It is an object - pure and simple and declared as an object.  The OP described their data structure as an object so that's how I wrote my answer, but didn't show the actual code so we can't know for sure.  Why downvote me for that?  Odd.  And, by the way, my answer seems to have solved their issue too.

Comment: @jfriend00 I can see that. but as an answer, it's a bad one, the actual **Relevant** answer is in a mini comment (in the P.S section) and poorly described. it belong as comment on the original question. with so much REP, you should know that..

Comment: @avrahamcool Indeed you are partially correct, maybe I should have given the structure in JSON. The thing is that it was quite bigger than reported, so I tried only describing the parts I wanted. Inside my Object, there is another object, named data, that holds some Arrays, that each one of these Arrays holds a number of Objects (0, 1, 2, etc) as described above.

Comment: @dearn44 - for the future, please use actual Javascript object literal syntax to show your data.  As you can see your made-up syntax did not clearly communicate your actual data structure.  I've added a part to my answer at the end that shows an array.

Comment: Will do. I hoped my description would make things easier. It was obviously a bad idea. Yet for the problem described, you solution works.

Comment: @dearn44 - Including ACTUAL code is pretty much always the best thing to doin these questions  since it can never fail to communicate what you are actually doing.  Additional words are usually helpful, but leaving out the actual code (in this case the actual data structure in Javascript) make it easy to misunderstand.

Comment: @avrahamcool - Now that the OP has clarified the data structure, I added a section to my answer for an Array inside a nested object.

Answer (score -1):

You can use getters:

```
var obj = {
   data: [
      { name: "John" }
   ],
   get full() { return this.data[0].name + " Smith"; }
}
```

Comment: Read the comments from avrahamcool below my answer about why my answer was downvoted and it might give you a guess where the downvote came from.